# OpenOffice Dll Not Working After Deploying in IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, openoffice-calc

I have created an ASP.NET application in which I am creating an OpenOffice .calc File and storing it to my project folder.. Everything works fine in local machine.. But if I deploy it to IIS it is not working... What will be the reason??

Error I'm getting is: **Could not load file or assembly 'cli_uno.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem, i just changed in `dcomcnfg` (in DCOM configuration) properties for OpenOffice.
Change in **Identity tab** to **interactive user**.

Btw. check in your IIS7 **APPPOOL** (advanced settings) what Identity is set, mb it dont have premissions (try *NetworkService*, if not working go *LocalSystem* <- not recomemnded, i think it was about security)

Btw2. Oh and i forgot. Under Identity in II7 apppool u have *loadUserProfile* - set it to **true**

Also, it can be in DCOM configuration in **Localization tab**, try this too if its not working.

Comment: Its because IIS dont have premission to run OO

Comment: Now i m getting this error, <b>Could not load file or assembly 'cli_uno.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.</b>

Comment: how to give permission to run OO

Comment: have you added reference for that file? what other dlls are you using? nothing is blocking your OO? u can give 'All' in your premissions (properties on folder ->security)

Comment: i m using six cli_*.dlls which is kept inside my project folder and gave full controls to that folder

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411020/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies#comment22104338_4412076

Comment: You have to add reference to files... in right click on project -> add reference...

Comment: ya already referenced the .dll's and also placed the .dll's in bin folder manually as well

Comment: Have you checked APPPOOL .net version? have you set it to 4.0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63015/discussion-between-manikandan-k-and-buzka91).