# Error message: "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Full error messsage: `Could not load file or assembly 'LimitlessSoft.Buffer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)`

First of all I have looked at these questions and all of their answers:

- [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)
- [Could not load file or assembly (custom dll) - works for console but fails for web project (ASP.NET MVC 5) [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874259/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-custom-dll-works-for-console-but-fails-for-w?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Could not load file or assembly '***.dll' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411020/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

I haven't found any solution that is working for me.

Here is my situation.

I have winform `.NET Framework 4.0` project (no I cannot update to higher version). I had some code in it which I wanted to separate in `dll` so I can use it in some other project. I have created new `.NET Framework 4.0 Class Library` project which has only one class and it looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace LimitlessSoft.Buffer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to buffer data
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class Buffer<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate that returns object that is buffered
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public delegate T SetBuffer();
        /// <summary>
        /// SetBuffer that returns object that is buffered
        /// </summary>
        private SetBuffer UpdateBuffer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates when has buffer been updated last time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
        private T Value { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes new buffer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updateBuffer">Delegate that returns object being buffered</param>
        public Buffer(SetBuffer updateBuffer)
        {
            UpdateBuffer = updateBuffer;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets item from buffer that has been last time updated not greater than maximumObselence.
        /// If it cannot be found, he will do as updateIfNotFound says.
        /// If it cannot be foudn after updateIfNotFound, you will get default(T)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maximumObselence">Maximum obselence for buffered item</param>
        /// <param name="updateIfNotFound">Indicates if buffer need to be updated if it has not been found at given period</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Get(TimeSpan maximumObselence, bool updateIfNotFound = true)
        {
            if (Value != null)
                if ((LastUpdate - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds < maximumObselence.TotalMilliseconds)
                    return Value;

            if (updateIfNotFound)
            {
                Value = UpdateBuffer();
                LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                return Value;
            }

            return default(T);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets item into buffer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        public void Set(T item)
        {
            Value = item;
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Updates data in buffer
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            Value = UpdateBuffer();
            LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

When I import this class library in my project it drops error.

***Then I created new empty `.NET Framework 4.0 winform application`***, imported this `dll`, initialized class, called function from it and poof it is working.

Why does same dll works in new empty project but drops error on other one?

Comment: Have you read through this one? [error-a-strongly-named-assembly-is-required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290980/error-a-strongly-named-assembly-is-required)

Comment: Do both project have Solution file? Usually it doesn’t give error if u are building in a project scope